# Prevent all scripts, images and file downloads on unsafe sites

Tags: windows-7, firefox, security, internet

Is there any way that I can disable all scripts, images, and file downloads on websites that Web of Trust marks as unsafe (according to my settings)?

I am using Firefox 8 (64-bit) on Windows 7.

Comment: Woah! Firefox 8! Do you mean IE 8 or FF 5?

Comment: Firefox nightly. They just switched to 8 yesterday. Trying to catch up to Chrome I guess...

Comment: Well then I'm not sure (although I'm not sure in release FF either.) Sure someone will know though!

Comment: I can confirm this: http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/nightly/latest-trunk/

Comment: Jesus, at this rate, we'll have Firefox v99 by December!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the list of unsafe hosts to your hosts file.  Here's an [example](http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hosts.htm).

Comment: I did that. I think I took the list from that example, as well as Spybot's. But there are way too many sites that WOT blacklists for me, so it would be easier to disable everything in the browser instead.

Comment: I looked around the WOT site and it doesn't look like there's a way to retrieve the list of blacklisted sites.  You might want to request this feature for the WOT extension.

Comment: That's a good idea. Doing it now...